OCI peering VCN in the same region but different tenancies with an upgraded DRG
I am trying to create a connection between 2 vcns from two different tenancies.
I am following this doc to do it: https://docs.oracle.com/en-us/iaas/Content/Network/Tasks/scenario_d.htm#scenario_dtask_b_dita
Below is the startup information:
Tenancy 1:

VCN A
DRG A

Tenancy 2:

VCN B

I setup the following resources in Tenancy 1:
Iam Policy R
define group vcnAdmin as xxxx
define group drgAdmin as xxxx
define tenancy acceptorVCN as xxxx
endorse group drgAdmin to manage drg-attachment in tenancy acceptorVCN
admit group vcnAdmin of tenancy acceptorVCN to manage drg in tenancy

where:

vcnAdminis the OCID of the Adminsitrators group that is in the Tenancy 2.
drgAdmin is the OCID of the Administrators group that is in Tenancy 1
acceptorVCN is the OCID of Tenancy 2

Iam Policy A
define tenancy requestorDRG as xxxx
define group drgAdmin as xxxx
define group vcnAdmin as xxxx
admit group drgAdmin of tenancy requestorDRG to manage drg-attachment in tenancy
endorse group vcnAdmin to manage drg in tenancy requestorDRG

where:

requestorDRG is the OCID of Tenancy 1
drgAdmin is the OCID of Administrators group in Tenancy 1
vcnAdmin is the OCID of Administrators group in Tenancy 1

I have added Iam Policy A in the Tenancy 2 as well with the same OCIDs.
I have then created a DRGin Tenancy 1 and created a VCN attachment and attached my VCN 1 with it. This was successfull.
Now when i try to attach VCN 2 using a cross tenancy attachment, i am getting the following error:
Vcn: ocid1.vcn.oc1.af-johannesburg-1.xxx does not exist or you are not authorized to access it

Is there something i am missing ?

vcnAdmin is the OCID of the Adminsitrators group that is in the Tenancy 2.
drgAdmin is the OCID of the Administrators group that is in Tenancy 1.
^^
You define group with the name and OCID. In this case you are saying define group vcnAdmins as the OCID of a group called Administrators. I would try to create the groups with the name you set (new group vcnAdmin in Tenancy 2 and new group drgAdmin in Tenancy 1) and add your user into them - then reference the OCIDs for those groups

I have just tried it and i am getting the same issue.
